# how could you get the number of radio input checked using useRef in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code checks the number of radio buttons *checked* and applies some logic on matching inputs. I am using `document.querySelectorAll()` but I read I should use `useRef` instead. Now if I send a *ref* to the input button, expression `myref.current.length` is `undefined`.

How can I grab and check the length using useRef instead?

```js
const handleValue = (event) => {
  // 1 Get value of button
  setValue(event.target.value);

  // 2 Grab select menu (might use useRef)
  let myMenu = document.getElementById('myMenuSelect');

  // 3 Grab only input checked (might use useRef)
  let inputBtnRadio = document.querySelectorAll(
    'input[name="myBtnDiscount"]:checked'
  );

  // 4 If number of input is equal or bigger than 1
  if (inputBtnRadio.length >= 1) {
    // 5 Set select menu to first option
    myMenu.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

First think what you wanna do is wrap all the radio input inside  tag and set the ref of div like `<div ref={radiosRef}>{...radio input here...}</div>` and grab the collection of the radio with `radiosRef.current.childNodes` and you can got the length inside it.

**example:**

```
const radiosRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (radiosRef.current !== null) {
      console.log(radiosRef.current.childNodes.length)
    }
  }, [radiosRef])
  
  return (
    <div ref={radiosRef}>
      <input type="radio" name="test" />
      <input type="radio" name="test" />
      <input type="radio" name="test" />
      <input type="radio" name="test" />
      <input type="radio" name="test" />
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

***radio type input*** is basically used for checking ***only one item*** is selected like gender (you choose only once between male and female). You should use ***checkbox type input*** which is generally used for ***selecting multiple items*** from the user. You can declare a ***useState hook*** to track how many items are selected by a user. You also can check this documentation:
[How to handle and manage radio buttons state in React](https://surajsharma.net/blog/react-handle-radio-buttons)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() { 
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    // In Here, Apply the condition and Update the count state 
    setCount(count + 1);
}
```